# How to change value of DIO pin in TI Launchpad cc1350

Tags: iot, lcd

I've been trying to change pin's value so it will output high or low voltage using the following code:

Initialize:

```
    PIN_Config LCDInitTable[] = {
    // DIO2: Buzzer (initially off)
    Board_DIO25_ANALOG |  PIN_GPIO_OUTPUT_EN | PIN_GPIO_LOW | PIN_PUSHPULL,
    // DI03: E
    PIN_ID(3)  | PIN_GPIO_OUTPUT_EN | PIN_GPIO_LOW | PIN_PUSHPULL ,
    // DIO23: Rs
    PIN_ID(23)  | PIN_GPIO_OUTPUT_EN | PIN_GPIO_LOW | PIN_PUSHPULL,
    // DIO22: D4
    PIN_ID(22) | PIN_GPIO_OUTPUT_EN | PIN_GPIO_LOW | PIN_PUSHPULL,
    // DI24: D5
    PIN_ID(24)  | PIN_GPIO_OUTPUT_EN | PIN_GPIO_LOW | PIN_PUSHPULL,
    // DIO10: D6
    PIN_ID(10)  | PIN_GPIO_OUTPUT_EN | PIN_GPIO_LOW | PIN_PUSHPULL,
    // DIO21: D7
    PIN_ID(21)  | PIN_GPIO_OUTPUT_EN | PIN_GPIO_LOW | PIN_PUSHPULL,
    // Terminate list
    PIN_TERMINATE
    };
    static PIN_Handle lcdHandle;
    static PIN_State lcdState;
```

And then in the main function:

```
lcdHandle = PIN_open(&lcdState, LCDInitTable);
if(!lcdHandle) {
    /* Error initializing board LED pins */
    while(1);
}
PIN_setOutputValue(lcdHandle, Board_DIO25_ANALOG, 1);

BIOS_start();
```

Here I tried to change to voltage to be high
If anyone knows how to pass data to the LCD 16bit it would be great (I'm using it as an 8bit)
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Board_DIO25_ANALOG |  PIN_GPIO_OUTPUT_EN | PIN_GPIO_LOW | PIN_PUSHPULL,

Wasn’t the correct flags